# how to get data from MPU6050 to maixduino k210 board using micropython language and maixpy ide software?

Tags: c++, c, i2c, micropython

I have maixduino k210 board and MPU6050 sensor. It has been connected with pins and maixduino k210 board and maixpy ide connected with i2c communication. Now, I want to bring MPU6050 censor data to Maixduino K210 board.

Please give me a advice for this.